# How to loop over objects nested in objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an object two layers deep that I'm trying to loop over:

```
const sections: object = {sectionA: {density1: "content_1"}, sectionB: {density1: "content_1"} 

function makeSectionGrid(sections: object){
  const sectionGrid: JSX.Element[] = []

  for (let section in sections){
    for (let density in section){
      let content: string = section[density]
      sectionGrid.push(<div>{content}</div>)
    }
  }
}
```

The TypeScript compiler complains about `for (let density in section)`:

> The right-hand side of a 'for...in' statement must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter, but here has type 'string'

Am I supposed to cast section? I've tried that, and it isn't working. Not sure how to make the error go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to add some interfaces:

```
interface SectionInterface {
    [density: string]: string;
}

interface SectionsInterface {
    [key: string]: SectionInterface; 
}

const sections: SectionsInterface = {
    sectionA: { density1: "content_1" }, sectionB: { density1: "content_1" }
}

function makeSectionGrid(sections: SectionsInterface) {
  const sectionGrid: any[] = []

  for (let section in sections){
    for (let density in sections[section]){
        let content: string = sections[section][density];
        sectionGrid.push(content);
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoQWYB7EBJcaeJZAbwChkrkBtAEwhAGdgwBPALmSbClAHMAulx58Q-ANzkAvuXKhIsRCnSYczAouIoK1WgGsInbrwHC0GLLk1FlE5DLkJcPbpfVMuqqxsJKSALxklNRM7rgAglykyAzMrGwAjFwARM6E4AD6iSnI0gA0bmq4AELRsYws7MnIabiQWTl5juQwAK4gxSDIALZwht7qAOJ8dAAUYV2eFlM2-hAAlMFU6a6TPiPAdFxwIGw0gshBB3JUMNhQyGMANhBgRT7IoA8eC7rU55c3dxXx7E-ddYeGhA3CCN4hPRUW73dINMAiUziI4vFwg8IgQT0SoJQRSKGhDGbOgAOgADm0mAALMZwxhgBb46iyKiyaRAA)